# Отправить текущий буфер на stdin внешней программе и вставить ее вывод в текущую позицию

Tags: vim

Чтобы вставить вывод внешней программы в текущую позицию в vim, я пишу, к примеру,

```
:r !wc -l %
```

Как вместо имени файла как аргумента командной строки послать на stdin программе текущий буфер и точно так же вставить вывод внешней программы в текущую позицию?

Comment: можно пропустить текущий буфер через фильтр. что приведёт к потере текущего содержимого. чтобы его сохранить, [можно фильтровать новый буфер (скопировав туда содержимое текущего)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4431/2338).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нашел, чтобы это можно было сделать командами.

Завернул в функцию и слегка модифицировал код [отсюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21531120/9087302) Вот что получилось:

```
function PipeIt(cmd)
   return system(a:cmd, join(getline(1,'$'), "\n"))
endfunction
```

Тогда получим требуемое, запустив команду:

```
:put =PipeIt('внешнее_приложение арг1 арг2')
```